# How many output file can be generated using outfil of sort utility?

Tags: mainframe, jcl, syncsort, dfsort

In a simple JCL script I am trying to generate some similar datasets according to some conditions using SORT.  In this way how many output files can I generate in a single JCL?

Comment: Lots. Show what you have, describe more clearly what you want to do, state which SORT product you have (DFSORT or SyncSORT) and get rid of the COBOL tag, please.

Comment: Something deficient in the Answer?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who wants to try it, here's a DFSORT step which will generate 1629 DD statements (SYSOUT=*) and 1629 OUTFIL statements.

Run the step.

Take a SORT step which just has OPTION COPY and using the ISPF editor, copy the dataset from SYSOUTS into the JCL part, and the dataset from OUTFILS after the OPTION COPY.

Submit your job. If it fails with n-number of `IEF649I EXCESSIVE NUMBER OF DD STATEMENTS` then delete the last n-number DD statements and the last n-number OUTFIL statements. If it works, you can try higher numbers of DD statements (change both the 1629s) especially if your TIOT-size is greater than 32K. With a 64K TIOT you'll probably be able to get a little over twice this number.

Don't be surprised if it takes some time (it won't be too long), as it is opening, writing a record to, and closing all those files.

```
//LOTSOFOF EXEC PGM=SORT 
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=* 
//OUTFILS DD DISP=(,CATLG),UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(TRK,2),
// DSN=your dataset name number 1 here 
//SYSOUTS DD DISP=(,CATLG),UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(TRK,2),
// DSN=your dataset name number 2 here 
//SYSIN    DD * 
  OPTION COPY 

  OUTFIL REPEAT=1629, 
         FNAMES=OUTFILS, 
         BUILD=(C' OUTFIL FNAMES=F', 
                SEQNUM,4,ZD, 
                80X) 
  OUTFIL REPEAT=1629, 
         FNAMES=SYSOUTS, 
         BUILD=(C'//F', 
                SEQNUM,4,ZD, 
                C' DD SYSOUT=*', 
                80X) 
//SORTIN   DD * 
ONE LINE NEEDED, CONTENT NOT IMPORTANT
```

There is an XTIOT (Extended TIOT), but that is not for QSAM, that has specialised uses like for DB2.

---

Well, the answer is known anyway.

There are effectively two limits to the number of OUTFIL statements you can have.

The first is how many DDnames your site allows in a single jobstep. Ask your seniors or a Sysprog how big the TIOT is. If it is 32K, you'll have around 1,600 available. If 64K, twice that.

The second limit is the number of SORT control cards you have in the step and their complexity. You can still get lots.

Either way, I suspect you'll have easily more than enough OUTFIL statements for your task.

How many do you want?

For doubters, try this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/bit.listserv.ibm-main/km3VNDp0SQQ/Zmh161dcSKcJ

The relevant quote from Kolusu is:

```
DFSORT was able to handle writing up to 999 members into a PDSE
simultaneously.   Beyond that I get  IEF649I EXCESSIVE NUMBER OF DD
STATEMENTS
```

Indicating that DFSORT was still happy in this case, and that z/OS was not. Kolusu is a developer of DFSORT.

If there are more denials, I can find more quotes, including from Frank Yaeger, inventor, designer and developer of the modern DFSORT for many, many, years (now retired).

Comment: But one of my senior told me that it is 32

Comment: @DUSMANTA But you asked here so that you'd get a good answer, not to show that one of your senior's doesn't know what they are talking about on this issue. Some people when asked and they don't know will give you rubbish so that they "look good". Until caught out. You don't have to believe me, the answer may help other people anyway. You also haven't said how many you want. I guess more than 32...?

Comment: @DUSMANTA A further update. You can try this at work. I'd love to know what your senior thinks, but it may not be diplomatic to show it to them :-)